# In WCF Data Services, how can I change the visible name of my entities?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf-data-services

Using WCF Data Services I am using a data model that contains entities with names specific to the model. I would like to expose them through Odata but with different names.

For example, we have an entity called *UserWithLeastPrivilege* and that is a problematic name to say the least. I would like the Odata client to simply see *User*. **Can you do this?**

This:

```
<service>
  <workspace>
    <atom:title>Default</atom:title>
    <collection href="UsersWithLeastPriv">
      <atom:title>UsersWithLeastPriv</atom:title>
    </collection>
  </workspace>
</service>
```

Becomes:

```
<service>
  <workspace>
    <atom:title>Default</atom:title>
    <collection href="User">
      <atom:title>User</atom:title>
    </collection>
  </workspace>
</service>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not easy to achieve. The EF provider doesn't allow this kind of customization currently. You would have to implement a custom provider over your EF model which is a LOT of work.